# Storing the residual for each group

Tags: regression, linear-regression, stata, data-manipulation

I am trying to run regression analysis in `Stata` with different `year` and `group`:

```
generate y = .

areg X1 X2 X3 if year == 1997, absorb(group)
predict r1997, res
replace y = r1997 if e(sample)

areg X1 X2 X3 if year == 1998, absorb(group)
predict r1998, res
replace y = r1998 if e(sample)

areg X1 X2 X3 if year == 1999, absorb(group)
predict r1999, res
replace y = r1999 if e(sample)
```

However, if there are many `year` and `group`, this is inefficient.

I can use `bysort`, which will run the regression by group, but not store the residual for each group.

How can I modify my code to make it more efficient for storing the residual for each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it this is just one loop. See [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/) for an elementary introduction.

Suppose your years run 1997-2018:

```
generate wanted = . 

forvalues y = 1997 / 2018 { 
    areg X1 X2 X3 if year == `y', absorb(group)
    predict work, res
    replace wanted = work if e(sample)
    drop work 
}
```

The code is self-explanatory if you think about it. Variable `work` is where I put residuals. They cannot be put in `wanted` because predict needs a new variable name. Other way round, next time around the loop, I cannot use `work` again unless it no longer exists, which is why it is dropped once its values have been copied to `wanted`.